# Mysql запрос не выводит корректно

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет. Есть запрос:

```
SELECT PK_ID,FK_Unit_IMEI,MIN(PositionDateTime) date_time,Last_PositionDateTime,Longitude,Latitude,Speed,Last_Longitude,Last_Latitude,Speed,Direction,Altitude,InsertDateTime, TIMEDIFF(max(PositionDateTime), min(PositionDateTime))  P FROM `fleet_6`
 WHERE `PositionDateTime` >= '".$date_in."' AND `PositionDateTime`  <= '".$date_out."' AND 'P' >= '".$stop."' AND Speed = 0 AND FK_Unit_IMEI = '".$_POST['car']."' GROUP BY Latitude,Longitude
```

Есть дата `PositionDateTime`, я беру высчитываю, сколько общих минут в таблице по дате, потом хочу, чтобы выводил от переменной, например, вывод:

```
('P' >= '".$stop."')от 00:25:00.
```

## 1054 - Unknown column 'P' in 'where clause' почему так?

mysql не видет P, хотя я объявил её! Как можно обойти это?

Comment: @chambo, mysql не видит **поля** P. Это ключевой момент, выборка делается по существующим в таблице полям, а не вычисляемым в select выражениям. Другое дело, что в WHERE разрешено вычисление значений.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно писать `AS P`

[Тут](http://www.geeksengine.com/database/basic-select/column-alias.php) примеры.

Comment: @A1essandro, AS писать необязательно.